# Why does the CSS of YouTube's comment section have two "line-height"s?

Tags: css, youtube

If I open a random YouTube video like this ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jmel5YySUXU ), and inspect the style of a comment in the developer tools, I see that there are two line-height, and the first one is cancelled out.

[image]

If I click the "inline:18451", I see the code like below, but I cannot find this in the source code of the web page, so I guess it is somehow dynamically created. My question is that why there are two `line-height` properties. Is there some meaning to this, or is this simply a bug (that the programmer forgot the first one, and added a second one later)?

```
#content-text.ytd-comment-renderer {
  --yt-endpoint-color: var(--yt-spec-call-to-action);
  --yt-endpoint-hover-color: var(--yt-spec-call-to-action);
  --yt-endpoint-visited-color: var(--yt-spec-call-to-action);
  color: var(--yt-spec-text-primary);
  font-size: var(--ytd-user-comment_-_font-size); font-weight: var(--ytd-user-comment_-_font-weight); line-height: var(--ytd-user-comment_-_line-height); letter-spacing: var(--ytd-user-comment_-_letter-spacing);
  line-height: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: only Youtube can answer your question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably just a typo.

Someone came later on trying to fix a problem, and didn't notice there was already a `line-height` attribute there.

With CSS in the same selector, the last mention of an attribute overwrites any previous one, unless of course they use `!important`.

From just experience, people tend to make mistakes.